# Azure queue throttling error with few requests (StorageException: The server is busy)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

- Language: C#
- Framework: .NET CORE 1.1.1
- Nuget: WindowsAzure.Storage version 8.1.1

Hi,

I use a queue storage on Azure.
I have 4 programs which make each 1 request/second (GetMessagesAsync request).
So I make 4 request/seconds.

But sometimes, there is throttling errors that results on this exception :

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The server is
>   busy.) ---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The
>   server is busy.\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.d__4`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.<>c__DisplayClass83_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n

**I don't know why I get this error given that Azure target throughput for single queue is up to 2000 messages per second.**

Additional informations :

- My messages are small json files (1ko size)
- I checked on my azure portal and in 7 days my programs made 2.2M requests (~3.6 requests/sec)
- When I get the "Server is busy" exception I also get throttling errors in my azure portal

My function where I make the get :

```
protected async Task<IEnumerable<CloudQueueMessage>> GetAndDequeueMessagesAsync(int numberOfMessagesToRetrived = 1) {
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<CloudQueueMessage> messages = await GetMessagesAsync(numberOfMessagesToRetrived);
                foreach (CloudQueueMessage queueMessage in messages)
                {
                    await DequeueMessageAsync(queueMessage);
                }
                return messages;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {                
                return new List<CloudQueueMessage>();
            }            
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, if you send too many requests per second at one time. The storage server will return 503 error. Have you enable minute metrics[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-enable-and-view-metrics] for the queue storage? I suggest you could enable it. You could see have many request per minute. If the number is exceed 2000, storage will return 503. Another is some other program has used the same queue and match the 2000 message per seconds. I suggest you could also check it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Like I said in my post, I already checked the metrics and it's say 2.2M requests in 7 days. Which is ~3.6 requests / sec. This is a ridiculous number compared to the 2000 messages per second allowed by azure.

For your second point, the metrics in azure are for the queue independently of how many programs use it.

Comment: In my opinion, 2.2M requests in 7 days doesn't mean 3.6 requests / sec. It is just average value. Besides, the storage also have the targets: Maximum Request Rate per storage account: Queues: 20,000 messages per second (assuming 1 KB message size).If your exceed this value, it will also show the error. As far as I know, azure storage will not return the 503 error immediately after you exceed the targets. If you exceed the targets for a while(about 1 minutes) it will return the 503 error.

Comment: Basically I got 4 programs who make one request each second (it's a loop with a 1 second sleep).

This way, my request usage is "stable". There is no peak usage.

Each hour, I make ~14k requests (which is ~3.8 requests / sec).

See my chart (when there is a drop, it's one of my program who received an "server is busy" error) https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrgSD.jpg

 So I don't understand why I got this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I guess the reason is the storage service moving partitions to improve load balancing.

As far as I know, the azure storage partition server will not just host one partition(queue\table partition-key), it will host many partitions.

If the partition server receive too many request, azure storage will automatic improve load balancing.

It will move some partitions to another partition server. If you send reqeust when moving the partition it will return 503 error.

More details about how the azure storage improve load balancing. You could refer to this [azure storage SOSP article's 5.5.1 Load Balance Operation Details](http://sigops.org/sosp/sosp11/current/2011-Cascais/printable/11-calder.pdf) .

I suggest you could implement retry policies using the Storage Client Library to keep your program working well.

More details, you could refer to below article:
[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.RetryPolicies Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/JJ682754.aspx)

Comment: To add one finer point, Table Storage has limits per partition. If you have millions of records in a single partition and heavy transaction volume, you'll be limited. If you partition your table storage data, you can achieve a higher throughput by spreading out over multiple partitions, each with its own service limit.